# Unity Colliders don't work as expected - I go through it or detect collision without touch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, rigid-bodies

I have predetermined path with Asteroidst. Asteroid has RigidBody and box collider.[Imagewith path and asteroid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7ZCp.png)

**My Player object** has spaceship, camera and Particle System.

Player object follow path with script that uses ***rigidbody.position.***

```
   Rigidbody rb;

void Start()
{              
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update()
{
distanceTravelled += speed * Time.deltaTime;
rb.position = pathCreation.path.GetPointAtDistance(distanceTravelled) + side ;
transform.rotation = pathCreation.path.GetRotationAtDistance(distanceTravelled);
}
```

Problem when my spaceship move on this path with left and right offset Vector3(0,1 or -1,0), sometimes collider work as expected, or register OnCollisionEnter when I didn't touch asteroid, and sometimes I can go through asteroid, even though it has collider and rigid body.

My SPACESHIP also has collider and RIGIDBODY. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNcEa.png)

I move spacehip relative to parent with script (Player is a parent of the spaceship's parent. I move with this script)

```
 void FixedUpdate()
{
     if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){   move_right = false;  move_left = true;  }
     if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)){ move_left = false; move_right = true;  }

     if(move_left){
     transform.localPosition =  Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition, left, horisontal_amplif * 0.03f);
         Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, targetRotationLeft, horisontal_amplif *  1f);
             if(Vector3.Distance(transform.localPosition,left) < 0.03f){move_left = false; }   

        }
     if(move_right){
    transform.localPosition =  Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition, right, horisontal_amplif * 0.03f);
         transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, targetRotationRight, horisontal_amplif * 1f  );
         if(Vector3.Distance(transform.localPosition,right) < 0.03f){move_right = false; }  
        }
 
}
```

I've tried Rigidbody.move, Rigidbody.position and Charactercontroller.Move

I DETECT COLLISION with this script

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo){
    GameObject player = GameObject.Find("player");
         if(collisionInfo.gameObject.CompareTag ("Obstacle")){ 
        Debug.Log("DEAD");
        // End_game();
     }
        if(collisionInfo.gameObject.tag == "speedUP"){ 
        Debug.Log("speed UP");
            horisontal_amplif = 1.7f;
            player.GetComponent<move_cube> ().speed = 5f;

        Invoke("Normal_Speed", 3f);
}
}
```

I want precise collision detection. Now, collision detects hit even though I didn't touch asteroid, and I even can move through asteroid.

[SCRIPT which detect collision is on FOXY_spaceship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHhR3.png)

Comment: What if you set Collision detection to continuous on the player as well?

Comment: @MathewHD Continuous detection gives same result.

Comment: On which object is your OnCollisonEnter script ?

Comment: @MathewHD On FOXY_spaceship which inside of GameObject(whitch inside Player object with camera and particle system)

Comment: Just make sure that the script is on the same object that has the OnCollision Script

Comment: @MathewHD YES, it's on the same. OnCollisionEnter and FixedUpdate with code tahat move FOXY_spaceship are both in one script that FOXY_spaceship include.